# Create list that contains elements of an other list with a specific display order

Tags: algorithm, linked-list

Consider a singly-linked list L each element of which is a struct with two fields, an integer `num` and a pointer `next` to the next element of the list.

Describe an algorithm that gets as argument a pointer to the first element of the list L and that creates a new list L' that will contain all the elements of L ordered in the following way:

The elements of `L` for which the field `num` is an odd number have to appear in L' before all the elements of which the field `num` is an even number. The elements with odd number at the field `num` should keep in `L'` the display order that they had at the initial list `L`.

The same should hold for the elements with an even number at the field `num`.

For example, if the initial list is `L=13->15->20->17->24->26->9->30->53->44` the final list should be `L'=13->15->17->9->53->20->24->26->50->44`.

That's what I have tried:

```
struct node{
    int num;
    struct node next;
 }Node;

List(L){
  if (L==NULL) return;
  Node *p=NULL, *q=L, *l=L, *L3=NULL, *head2=NULL, *tail1=NULL, *tail2=NULL;
  while (q!=NULL){
        if (q-> num mod 2==1){
            if (p==NULL){
               p->num=q->num;
               L3=p;
            }
            else {
               p=p->next;
               p->num=q->num;
           }
        }
        q=q->next;
  }
  tail=p;
  while (l!=NULL){
        if (l-> num mod 2==0){
           if (l==NULL){
               l->num=q->num;
               head2=l;
            }
            else {
               l=l->next;
               l->num=q->num;
           }
        }
  }
  tail2=q;
  tail1->next=head2;
  tail1=tail2;
  return L3;
  }
```

Could you tell me if it is right?

Comment: if I am not getting it wrong the code is in c/c++ but you have not used assigned memory to pointers before assigning num a value ?

Comment: @sasha It is just a pseudocode, but it is C-like... I edited my post... Do I also have to change something else?

Comment: the first bug I see is that the first while loop runs forever you have not done q=q->next

Comment: I tried to write a complete code so that no confusion is there hope it helps :) Also for future reference post a complete code with explanatory variable names and comments in code to explain what you are doing

Comment: Could you explain me why newhead returns at the end of the function the whole new list? @sasha

Comment: its the head to the new list, first it adds all odd numbers of the new list in order then in second loop adds all even numbers in order and then the newhead ( pointer to head of new list you desire ) is returned

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried to make few changes keeping your code the same

```
struct node{
int num;
struct node next;
}node;

List(L){
    if (L==NULL) return NULL;
    node *p=NULL, *q=L, *l=L, *newhead=NULL;
    while (q!=NULL){
        if (q-> num % 2==1){
              if (p==NULL){
                  p=(node *)malloc(sizeof(node));
                  p->num=q->num;
                  p->next=NULL;
                  newhead=p;
              }
              else {
                 node * tmp;
                 tmp=(node *)malloc(sizeof(node));
                 tmp->num=q->num;
                 tmp->next=NULL;
                 p->next=tmp;
                 p=tmp;

             }
      }
    q=q->next;
  }
  while (l!=NULL){
        if (l-> num % 2==0){
               if (p==NULL){
                  p=(node *)malloc(sizeof(node));
                  p->num=q->num;
                  p->next=NULL;
                  newhead=p;
               }
               else {
                  node * tmp;
                  tmp=(node *)malloc(sizeof(node));
                  tmp->num=q->num;
                  tmp->next=NULL;
                  p->next=tmp;
                  p=tmp;

            }
       }
       l=l->next;
 }

 return newhead;
 }
```